# How can I optimise below Python code to run faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci

This is the code for returning two consecutive numbers of Fibonacci series whose product is passed in `fib()` function. If the product exceeds the given number, the code ends by returning those two numbers and `False` in the `list` as shown.

This takes a huge time to run for larger numbers.
Can someone help me with the optimization of this code?

```
def fib(n):
    if n<=1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)


def productFib(prod):           
    i = 0
    while i >= 0:
        a = fib(i)*fib(i+1)
        if a == prod:
            return [fib(i), fib(i+1), True]
        elif a > prod:
            return [fib(i), fib(i+1), False]
        i+=1
    
        
print(productFib(41)) # [8, 13, False]
print(productFib(40)) # [5, 8, True]
print(productFib(4895)) # [55, 89, True]
print(productFib(5895)) # [89, 144, False]
```

Fibonacchi series:

> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, ... .

Comment: Use iterative generation of fibonacci numbers: https://medium.com/@danfcorreia/fibonacci-iterative-28b042a3eec

Comment: You call `fib(i)` and `fib(i+1)` three times each instead of once and storing the result. You can improve the efficiency of the `fib` function but you also need to optimize how you call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiboncci function is very slow, because you're doing the same calculation again and again. It's a very well known problem, to solve that either you can use an iterative approach or use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Fortunately, you don't need to write a code for it. Python has built in support for caching functions via [`lru_cache`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/function_caching.html).

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=1000)
def fib(n):
    if n<=1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as this is a _Python_-specific solution. Self-rolling memoization seems absurd for this task so I especially appreciate the simplicity and directness of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of looking at your code, would be to avoid calling the function again while returning the result and store the Fibonacci variables beforehand.

```
def productFib(prod):           
    i = 0
    while i >= 0:
        fib_curr = fib(i)
        fib_next = fib(i+1)
        a = fib_curr * fib_next
        if a == prod:
            return [fib_curr, fib_next, True]
        elif a > prod:
            return [fib_curr, fib_next, False]
        i+=1
```

If you are planning to run the code multiple times for different values like you have given examples of the `print` staetements, you could optimise it by storing the Fibonacci values in a list upto a certain number, and then iterate through the list till a match is found, by this method at least your code won't have to calculate the same values repetitively.